# SSRS Report Viewer for iPad

Tags: ios, reporting-services

I'm working on a native iPad app in which I want to show SSRS Report which I get from REST web service. Is there any free native control or HTML5/jQuery control for viewing SSRS Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view SSRS's web service via a 'form' in HTML.  You tie the form's action to get it and then you may even set up other options as well in the form.  There may be ways to use client side scripting as well but I have not attempted those.  I do however know this works.

```
<form id="frmRender" action="http:// (servername)/(pathtoreport)" method="post" 
target="_self">
<H3>My Report Title</H3>
Render in the following format:<br/>
<Select ID="rs:Format" Name="rs.Format" size=1>
<Option Value="HTML4.0">HTML 4.0</Option>
<Option Value="IMAGE">TIFF IMAGE</Option>
</Select>
</form>
```

Generally the roof of an SSRS service to a report is typically

```
http:// (servername)/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f(directoryName)%2f(reportName)&rs:Command=Render
```

However if you want to do reporting with HTML5/Jquery I would do something like HighCharts IMHO: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/